# Xcode(Swift): I can't transfer data between View Controllers

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller

So I am creating an app, this app requires a password to initially log on and then that would take you to the main app where you can go to differant programs. The way I have the password view controller set up is that it has layers and in the swift files, I have a variable ('x') that changes based on certain circumstances. When the x value changes, what is on the view changes too. For example, the first layer is active when x = '1.0' and this means that the password has not been entered yet. When it is entered, x = '1.5' and it brings up a screen telling you that you got the password correct and a button apears leading you to the main page.
On the main page, I have a button that connects you back to the first page that allows you to change your passcode. I want the main page to change the x value so that the password page has a completly new page when you open it.
 
My problem is that I cannot get the segue to work. Here is the sample code for my 2 view controllers:

```
    import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var x = "1.0"
//First Page--------------------------------
@IBOutlet weak var Textbar: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var submitbutton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var enterYourPasscode: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var Welcome: UILabel!


//1.5-------------------------------
@IBOutlet weak var correct: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var Open: UIButton!

@IBAction func CloseKeyboard(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    self.resignFirstResponder()
}
var password="Ree"


@IBAction func SubmitClick(_ sender: Any) {
    if Textbar.text == password {
        x = "1.5"
        checkVersion()

    }else{
        enterYourPasscode.text="Wrong, try again."
    }
}

func checkVersion (){

    if x == "1"{
        correct.isHidden = true
        Open.isHidden = true

        Textbar.isHidden = false
        submitbutton.isHidden = false
        enterYourPasscode.isHidden = false
        Welcome.isHidden = false
    }
    if x == "1.5"{
        correct.isHidden = false
        Open.isHidden = false

        Textbar.isHidden = true
        submitbutton.isHidden = true
        enterYourPasscode.isHidden = true
        Welcome.isHidden = true
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {

    checkVersion()

    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

Here is the code for the view that I want to send the data:

```
    import UIKit

class ViewController2: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var Settings: UIButton!

@IBAction func GoToSettings(_ sender: Any) {





}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    var recievingController = segue.destination as! ViewController
    ViewController.x = "2.0"
}


}
```

The error shows up on the second view controller where it says, " viewController.x = '2.0' " and the error says, " Instance member 'x' cannot be used on type 'ViewController' "
 
I have spent a lot of time trying to figure out why it is doing this as I have done similar things in the past without a problem. I might just be overthinking it while there is an easy solution and that is why I am asking the community.
 
 **Edit:** My problem has been solved, thanks to all who put in help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you downcast the destination to be ViewController, you store it in the receivingController variable. Simple: just reference that variable:

```
receivingController.x = "2.0"
```

The error is gone. By the way, you spelled 'receiving' wrong :)

Comment: No problem. Accept the answer(click the check mark) and be sure to upvote :)

Comment: I don't have 15 reputation. I did, but it won't publically show it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go `recievingController.x` not `ViewController.x` in your second view because that is the instance of the viewController

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with your code.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    var recievingController = segue.destination as! ViewController
    ViewController.x = "2.0"
}
```

Try this:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    var recievingController = segue.destination as! ViewController
    recievingController.x = "2.0"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In a nutshell, the direct cause of the problem is:

```
var x = "1.0"
```

should be

```
public var x = "1.0"
```

However style-wise, it may be better to wrap this property up in a class called LoginManager, with a delegate that can update when something changes.